# Where to safely store client certificate / key used in scripts for mTLS?

Tags: ssl, curl, https, keychain, mtls

I am working on an HTTP application that will use [mTLS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/access-management/what-is-mutual-tls/) to authenticate requests coming from corporate hardware without requiring users to log in individually. However, unlike many such applications (normally websites), this is a script that will run when the computer boots. Currently I just have a bash script that starts and sends a CURL request.

```
curl https://myapp.example.com --cacert my-ca-crt.pem --key my-client-key.pem --cert my-client-crt.pem
```

The purpose of mTLS here is to ensure requests to this API are only accepted if they come from our company-provisioned devices. This is not an application where security is a business concern (no sensitive data being transferred), but I do want to do my best to lock it down properly.

We will use corporate IT tools to deploy the following to the hardware we are concerned about:

- Our own CA (used to sign both server and client certificate)
- The script that runs on boot
- The client certificate and key

However, CURL cannot (AFAIK) use the MacOS keychain like the browser can. Since I need to store a client certificate and key on the client, I'm wondering where the best place to put these is.

```
curl https://myapp.example.com --cacert my-ca-crt.pem --key /where/should/this/go/my-client-key.pem --cert my-client-crt.pem
```

Of course, the key is really the only thing that needs to be guarded.

I know that at the end of the day, when using a certificate/key with your browser for example, the data is technically readable by processes like that browser and even other users on the device in some cases. But there is at least some protection here:

1. The keys are stored in the OS keychain which is a pretty standard location
2. A password is required when the key is used (MacOS does support an "always allow" option)
3. The key / cert cannot be modified without a password

Storing the key on the device in a folder somewhere does not provide these advantages.

So, is there a way to get CURL to use the OS keychain somehow? It would be great to have an option like:

```
curl --use-os-keystore https://myapp.example.com
```

Or

```
curl --use-os-keystore https://myapp.example.com --cacert @keystore/my-ca-cert --key @keystore/my-client-key --cert @keystore/my-client-crt
```

I know these do not exist, just trying to illustrate the goal. Windows did add a [CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS.html) option to CURL in 7.71.0 but it works only on Windows, is marked as experimental, and does not help with the client key which is the only real concern because it only uses the native store for CA certs.

Since this is likely not an option, I'm also looking for guidance on where to store these certificates on the disk. Storing them in a random folder seems like a bad idea to me.

This is an area I'm not super familiar with so please let me know if there's any more information that would help or if I'm asking the wrong questions. Maybe there's a better way to ensure requests to this API are only accepted if they come from our company-provisioned devices?

To summarize:

1. Is there a way to get CURL to use the OS keystore or point to a cert inside the keystore?
2. Is there a place I can safely store private keys on disk outside of the keystore?
3. Is there a better way to do hardware-based authentication for an HTTP request made in a bash script on boot?

Comment: I don't have Mac but [curl claims to support SecureTransport](https://curl.se/docs/ssl-compared.html) which should use KeyChain -- is the one you have built that way? Check what `curl -V` says _just after_ `libcurl/$version`.

Comment: Have you tried `curl -E <identifier of our cert>` already? Docs say: (iOS and macOS only) If curl is built against Secure Transport, then the certificate string can either be the name of a certificate/private key in the system or user keychain, or the path to a PKCS#12-encoded certificate and private key. If you want to use a file from the current directory, please precede it with "./" prefix, in order to avoid confusion with a nickname.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 @Bram yep, this looks like it should work. Definitely more picky than I'd anticipated, and currently having issues getting the CA Cert picked up as well (which it says should be automatic if using `CURL_SSL_BACKEND=secure-transport` but that I can poke around at from here. If you want to provide a full answer I will mark it as correct.